# Android Studio Crash causing keystore issue

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

I recently tried to update my Android Studio and during the process is crashed. After re-installing I opened my app project pointed it to my original keystore file however my app wont update the existing version on any device as it says its signed with a different key. How do I get Android studio to sign it correctly?

Comment: Your keystore is not linked to android studio , it's just a "random" file. I don't think that an AS crash could corrupt your keystore. Try to open your keystore with a tool like keystore explorer to see if it's ok.

Comment: You're right. The AS crash didnt corrupt the key. I was using a different key which had the same name for some reason. All good now